# Render VF Page as PDF with LDS

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I have a lightning component that I need in the form of pdf. Since we can't do this in the lightning component.

I have to switch back to VF Page for pdf generation. Looks like when we use SLDS in vf page, it's not rendered as pdf.

Since my page is very complex, I don't want to do all the styling and other things.

What other options I have? Is there any js library that I can use with my vf page?

Answer (score 7):

Because of Lightning locker service, most of the third-party library which renders pdf won't work(at least I could not find any).

As a workaround, I would suggest this approach:

1. Create a Stylesheet with minimalistic styles for print media which would render a decent pdf and hide the other contents on-page and save it as a static resource.
2. Leverage Standard window.print web API to print pdf

Here is a sample code
**MyPdf.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName,flexipage:availableForRecordHome">
    <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.printableMedia}"/>

    <div class="section-to-print">
        <lightning:card title="my card">
            <h1>Hello world</h1>
        </lightning:card>

        <!-- Button component to invoke PDF download -->
        <lightning:button label="Download Document" 
                          onclick="{!c.downloadDocument}" />
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**MyPdfController.js**

```
 ({
        downloadDocument : function(component, event, helper) {
            window.print();
        }
 })
```

**printableMedia.css**

```
@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .section-to-print, .section-to-print * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .section-to-print {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

> This approach will only work where there is a user interaction
>   involved(not for sending emails automatically, consider using VF pages
>   in that case)

Comment: from where do I download the printableMedia resource?

Comment: use the CSS I have provided in my answer as a starter and save it as a static resource file

Comment: what's the use of <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.printableMedia}"/> ?

Comment: Global CSS property to hide other elements like a body can not be achieved directly from component CSS as a workaround I'm creating the css file as static resource and including it in the component. The css hides the body in print mode and only shows content inside section-to-print class

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing anything, do I need to add all of my styling in static resource, because currently it seems to be not working for me

Comment: Not all to style  you can add a @media print in component css as well for all existing css to reflect it in pdf also