# jsPDF Importing but not working in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, error, libraries

I tried to use jsPDF in LWC.
I uploaded jsPDF.min.js and html2cavas.min.js as static resources.

Then I load them in my component :

```js
import jspdf from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jspdf';
import html2canvas from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/html2canvas';

export default class TrhEmployeLeaveStatement extends LightningElement {

    jspdf = jspdf;
    html2canvas = html2canvas;

    connectedCallback() {
        // Load jspdf pdf lib from Static Resources
        loadScript(this, this.jspdf).then(() => {
            console.log("=== JSPDF LOADING ===");
            console.log("JSPDF loaded");
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("=== JSPDF LOADING ===");
            console.log("JSPDF not loaded")
        });

        // Load jspdf pdf lib from Static Resources
        loadScript(this, this.html2canvas).then(() => {
            console.log("=== html2canvas LOADING ===");
            console.log("html2canvas loaded");
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("=== html2canvas LOADING ===");
            console.log("html2canvas not loaded")
        });
    }
```

And the libs load correctly.
But when I test it with a simple code which works correctly outside LWC :

```js
async handleClickExtract() {
    const doc = new jsPDF();

    doc.html("<table><tr><td>Test11</td><td>Test12</td></tr><td>Test21</td><td>Test22</td></tr></table>",{
        callback: function(doc){
            doc.save();
        }
    })
}
```

But it prints me the following errror :

> Uncaught (in promise) Unable to find element in cloned iframe

Do you guys have any clue about this ? Has anyone got jsPDF working in LWC ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render VF Page as PDF with LDS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/298005/render-vf-page-as-pdf-with-lds)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know that almost a year has already passed, but I think that my method may be useful to someone.

```
    renderedCallback(){
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, jspdf+'/jspdf/jspdf.umd.min.js'),
        ])
    }

    generatePdf(){
        const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;

        const doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.text("Hello world!", 10, 10);
        doc.save("a4.pdf");
    }
```

First of all I load plugin in renderedCallback, and use it from globals module.

Comment: Have you tried this? I don't it will work.

Comment: @DhanikLalSahni, Yes. It works for me, from yesterday doesn't have any problems yet.

Comment: Hey, it's awesome, I've always thought that it didn't work because the library wasn't Locker Compliant !

Comment: @Moonvvell,
In LWC, the PDF is getting distorted, while it works well [otherwise](https://codepen.io/RitzSF/pen/xxgazoB)
Do you have any idea?
For further information, see: [Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67159676/multiple-pages-in-jspdf-autotable)

Comment: thanks, @Moonvvell!

Answer (score 5):

Because of the locker service, JSPdf is not supported in LWC. Check my answer to [generate pdf in LWC using standard browser API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/298014/69764).